# How do I make a bot say something when someone enter my discord server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I'm trying to make a discord bot say a certain message when it first joins a Discord Server, so when the bot first joins a Discord Server, it will say something along the lines of "Hello everyone....". I looked at a lot of sources but none seem to be,Can anyone help?

make a bot say a certain message when it first joins a server

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61721322/discord-py-join-leave-message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo.

To make your bot say something in a channel, you just use a client event.

Code example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
     await channel.send("Wassup!")
```

Please keep in mind that you need to define the channel variable.

Remember that this requires Intents.guilds to be enabled!
You can check all of this on the discord.py docs. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=event#discord.on_guild_join